# Use single streaming DataFrame for multiple output streams in PySpark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

There is a continuous stream of data, after all transformations it has next schema:

```
root
 |-- message_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- metric_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

There is also set of rules, i.e.:

```
if metric_id = 4077 and value > 10 and value < 25
```

That means if any row in a stream meets that condition, then this row must be pushed into a different stream.

How identify messages that meet alert criteria (there are several) and after push them to different stream?

Answer (score 2):

Spark Structured Streaming applications allow you to have multiple output streams using the same input stream.

That means, if for example `df` is your input streaming DataFrame you could just define a DataFrame filter and use the resulting, filtered DataFrame for another output stream as below:

```py
df = readStream.format(...).options(...).load().select(...)

# create a new DataFrame that only contains alters
alertsDf = df.filter( (df.metric_id == "4077") & (df.value > 10)  & (df.value < 45) )

# use both DataFrames for output streams
df.writeStream.format(...).options(...).start()
alertsDf.writeStream.format(...).options(...).start()

spark.streams.awaitTermination()
```

For fault-tolerance it is recommended to set the option `checkpointLocation` for each output stream separately.

Comment: now it's  'spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()'

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs the best way to do this it's using ForEachBatch, this is the exactly the use case described. [Structured Streaming - ForEachBatch docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)

So, reusing the above example, you will do something like this:

```
df = readStream.format(...).options(...).load().select(...)

# use both DataFrames for output streams in ForEachBatch
# And Applying transformations inside the ForEachBatch scope, but this can 
  happen outside

df.writeStream.foreachBatch((batch:df) =>
     df.write.format(...).options(location1),
     df.filter( (df.metric_id == "4077") & (df.value > 10)  & (df.value < 45) 
     ).write.format(...).options(location2)

)
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

I hope I've helped, thanks !

Comment: Best? Not really. Just possible. Be careful with fault-tolerance. What happens with partial writes?